# Cucumber:Assert values irrespective of Index

Tags: java, testing, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am working on updating functional test suites using Cucumber feature file.The issue my output is an array which is not sorted.Index of the object may change.

**Array:**

```
    [{

        "id": "12",
        "name": "Something"
    },
    {

        "id": "13",
        "name": "Another Something"
    }
 ]
```

Here I wanna assert name when Id=13 only.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Posted an answer. Please let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The `Json` is list of objects within an `Array` so you need parse them and validate the each `Object`. You can do like below,

**Code**:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(JsonAsString);
JSONObject jsonObject;

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
    if (jsonObject.get("id").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("13")) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + jsonObject.get("name"));
        //do your thing...
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Name: Another Something
```